# does setInterval inside a useEffect can recognize an updated state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gps, state, intervals

I'm working on an app which requires a user location every X seconds. When the component is mounted, the interval starts and fetch the GPS location and compare it to the old one which is saved on the component state.

The thing is, the interval is comparing only to the default state of the variable, so if the new value is different than the old one, a setter is called to change that value.
I used useEffect on the location var so whenever it changes, to just print it and it does correctly by the new value.

but the interval keeps using the default value given in useState hook.

What is it that I'm missing here.
An example of my code is below:

```
 const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(null);
 let locationInterval = null;

useEffect(() => {
      locationInterval = setInterval(async () => {
        console.log("IN INTERVAL");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location, error) => {
          if (location) {
            location = [location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude];

         /// currentLocation is not updating here for some reason

            if (JSON.stringify(location) !== JSON.stringify(currentLocation)) {
              alert(
                `the new location in interval ${location} old location: ${currentLocation}`
              );
              setCurrentLocation(location);
            }
          } else {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }, 15000);
  }, [map]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(locationInterval);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
/// currentLocation is updated here from the setInterval
    console.log("newlocation", currentLocation);
  }, [currentLocation]);
```

Comment: It seems like you missed the top  few lines of the code you wanted to share. Is the setInterval inside of a useEffect as well?

Comment: yes, fixed the post.

Comment: I just answered your question but on the side, need to mention there are other issues going on in your code ..things like your method of clearing the interval is not correct.

Comment: could you remove your native alert method, native alerts can block js execution. how about use console instead.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `currentLocation` value is not given as a dependency in the `useEffect`, therefore that `useEffect` callback function only has access to the original useState value.

May I ask are there any React warning on your terminal where you run your react app?
Something like

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'currentLocation'
```

But on the side node, if you add `currentLocation` to the dependency,since because you are updating `currentLocation` in your `useEffect` and if it's updated, it will re-run the useEffect callback again.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your answer, I've seen that you said something is off about my clearInterval...  the clear is working.. 
The thing is i've added the dependency of currentLocation as you said, but still inside the setInterval it's undefined (outside of setInterval but inside the useEffect its recognized)

Comment: I would do it this way https://codesandbox.io/s/geolocation-timer-mc8wx?file=/src/App.js you can check that the timer ticking date is stuck if there is no re-render of currentLocation state. if there is a re-render of currentLocation, the useCallback function set again and the useEffect is also new.

Comment: If you add currentLocation as dependency it will create new setInterval everytime you set current location. That's why I recommend to use useRef. I answered it below.

Comment: Zhang there're a lot of ways to to do it including your recommended method useRef but answering the OP's question `does setInterval inside a useEffect can recognize an updated state?` , i've created a sandbox and the answer is **yes**, setInterval inside a useEffect can recognize an updated state but need to be mindful of the dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get an updated state in `setInterval` because callback inside `useEffect` hook only called when its dependency array updates(`[map]`).
When it is called `currentLocation` is passed as a parameter to setInterval's callback. Which is the default value for `useState` at that time.

To prevent this you can do this.

```
const [currentLocationRef] = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  locationInterval = setInterval(async () => {
    //....
    if (JSON.stringify(location) !== JSON.stringify(currentLocationRef.current)) {
      currentLocationRef.current = location;
    }
  }, 15000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(locationInterval);
  };
}, [map, currentLocationRef]);
```

Also, you should return clearInterval in the same `useEffect` Callback.

The reason behind this is `currentLocationRef.current` is different from `currentLocation`. The first one is the getter function and the second one is value. That's why the first one is still able to access updated value while the second one cannot.